# Change label text with a button click in VBA

Tags: vb.net, forms, text, label

I'm new to VBA and I have the following code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
CommandButton2.Enabled = False

Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 14
    Me.Controls("textbox" & x).Value = ""
Next x

Application.DoEvents


'Probleeeeeeeeem

Me.Label8.Text = ""
Me.Label9.Text = ""
Me.Label10.Text = ""
Me.Label11.Text = ""
Me.Label12.Text = ""
Me.Label13.Text = ""

End Sub
```

The labels text (from 8 to 13) have already some values generated by another piece of code. How can I change those values to a void string with a `CommandButton3_Click()` ?
I tried `Application.DoEvents`and `Me.Refresh` but In vain, here is the error message I get :

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRBK7.png)

Thank you

Comment: VBA IsNot VB.NET and that is not VB.NET code.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and consult the usage guidance text on the tags.

Comment: Please be more descriptive what you want to achieve and what goes wrong. Textboxes containing values and you want them to be cleared and it doesn't  work? The code is supposed to fill textboxes with some values? Something different?

Comment: The string "textbox" should probably be "TextBox" for starters as that is the default case for TextBoxes - unless you have renamed them of course.

Comment: Part of asking good questions is telling us what behaviour you expect from the program, what behaviour youre actually getting and what any errors are and what line they occur on. Thanks You'll need to edit your question or it will be flagged as off-topic because you don't include these details.

Comment: BTW. I suspect that the code you want should be `Me.Update` placed afte rthe label assignments.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your remarks, I changed the subject based on your explanations